# Google Books API static link not working as expected

Tags: api, url, google-books, isbn

I am trying to implement a Google Books API request for books front coverages in my website.
According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/books/docs/static-links), all I need is to make a request with a static link: https://books.google.com/books?vid=ISBN{ISBN}&printsec=frontcover

I created a test link:
https://books.google.com/books?vid=ISBN0812511816&printsec=frontcover

However, instead of getting the cover, I'm getting the complete page of the book, not just the cover.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They changed the behavior of that call!

Now to get the cover, you have to use the internal id of the book (not the ISBN), e.g.:

```
https://books.google.com/books/content?id=ib7xnQAACAAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&source=gbs_api
```

Comment: But how do I know the internal ID of the book?

Comment: So i now basically need two API calls just to get the book cover? That’s unfortunate...

Comment: Yes! One to get the Google id and then another for the cover.

Comment: Thank you. That will take quite a while to test, I'll need to write a whole new PHP call. Also it doubles the amount of calls people need to make to the API, which makes no sense. I wonder why they did that. I mean, ISBN is ALREADY a unique identifier, that's the whole point of an ISBN number.

Comment: I think the intention was to make it more difficult! The reason? I don't know.